# Is a LAMJ stack a possible environment?

Tags: java, php, lamp

Is it possible to use Java instead of PHP with Linux, Apache and MySQL?

Comment: There is no opinion expressed in this question.

Comment: Since there is no ability to answer this properly, my answer here is "yes" it is possible; but, typically one would do a Linux / Tomcat / MySQL / Java combo, because Tomcat is the server of choice for handling Java based responses to HTTP requests.  Also, one would typically avoid MySQL in the Java world for Postgres, due to historical differences in approach between the PHP and Java crowds.  So you might encounter a LTPJ stack with an Apache front-end more often than a LAMJ stack.

Comment: Also of note, LAMP, had a lot more to do with finding talent and advertising a need for talent than it had to do with any specific framework.  For java web programming, one typically just asks for a Java developer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the 'LAMP' stack is not some special thing, only that there is a lot of support in the form or frameworks etc based on it. There is no problem to create an application based on Linux, Apache, MySQL and Java (LAMJ) but it will have totally different benefits and drawbacks than LAMP because Java is so totally different from PHP.

Where MySQL used to be the database of choice for Java developers I believe that has now shifted towards PostgreSQL. Some folk like [NoSQL databases](http://bigdata-madesimple.com/a-deep-dive-into-nosql-a-complete-list-of-nosql-databases/) like MongoDB but that really ties into the Java frameworks you want to use. Also you need some sort of web container to run your Java web application in. The most popular is still a web server like Tomcat I think, you could also use Jetty. For larger projects requiring more extensive application management support and clustering you could consider Glassfish or JBoss.

Maybe you should consider an LTPJ stack (Linux Tomcat PostgreSQL Java). I think that will give you more joy in the way of community support.

EDIT: 2019 update. In my perception the 'standard' has shifted to Spring Boot, with which you can run a web application as a standalone jar using an embedded Tomcat instance. Spring Boot offers a lot of out of the box support like Spring Actuator for management endpoints (e.g. application health).

Comment: Great answer! The only thing I would add is that HTTPS for production systems is a LOT easier to setup for Apache httpd than it is for Tomcat. So I would recommend setting up httpd as a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat. Let's Encrypt certs, for example, can be deployed/refreshed in an almost completely automated way to httpd.