# Java web application build procedure beginner using LAMP

Tags: java, webserver, lamp

I need to learn java programming, I have a LAMP server running and i need to build a webapplication(dynamic website). I have planned to use HTML, CSS, JS and Java for server side scripting instead of PHP using eclipse IDE. 
My question is does the above thing work out and also if i want to deploy the files do i need to send the files to /var/www/html/ or any other method of deployment is there ?

Comment: LAM**P** is, by definition, Linux (OS), Apache (HTTP server), MySQL (database), and **PHP** (programming language). So you are not running a LAMP stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a LAMJ stack a possible environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270077/is-a-lamj-stack-a-possible-environment)

Comment: can i use LAMC, Where c is for c++.

Comment: Yes. Look at [the framework 'Wt'](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is weird, but yes, you can make a application with Java for the server side, read about [JSP](http://www.jsptut.com/). And the files folder depends on the local server you're using , though most of the time for unix thats the right folder.

Good luck , I think you research a lot.

Edit: I was about to edit this for the LAMP definition, LAMP stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP... So you're not technically using that..

Comment: can i use LAMC, Where c is for c++.